# Sort records with attributes closest to search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Food` model that has 3 `decimal` attributes: `sweetness`, `spiciness`, and `saltiness`.

What I want to do is sort all the `Food` records based on how "close" they are to a search query.

So let's say the query for `[sweetness, spiciness, saltiness]` is `[1, 2, 3]`. In this case, a `Food` record with `[2, 3, 4]` attribute values should be ordered before a record with `[5, 6, 7]` attribute values.

I have a way to calculate the relative similarities between a query and a record using [Cosine Similarity](https://www.bionicspirit.com/blog/2012/01/16/cosine-similarity-euclidean-distance.html), but I am not sure how to sort them without iterating through all the records in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for the columns e.g., var1, var2, var3 in the search query. Now you can always use order by clause with var1.

Comment: You didn't really address my question. I know you can sort by column values, what I'm asking is a way to sort records based on their "overall closeness" to a three attribute query without iterating through the entire database.